# Calling multiple async operations in a C# class initializer

Tags: c#, .net, initialization, object-construction

Given a C# class like this

```
public class MyData
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Could it ever create a concurrency problem to instantiate and initialize this class like so:

```
var myInstance = new MyData
{
    Value1 = await MyFirstAsync(),
    Value2 = await MySecondAsync()
};
```

Assuming for example that MySecondAsync() relies on the same non-thread safe resources MyFirstAsync() does, or any other potential issue that could cause a pattern like this to be something to avoid?

Comment: It is just a syntactic sugar, so it should not differ by assigning them one by one.

Comment: Property initializers are executed sequentially, so as long as you `await` it you are fine.

Comment: _" it should not differ by assigning them one by one"_ - it doesn't indeed differ _at all_. Both calls are awaited, which means although _async_, they will be executed _sequentially_ ("one by one").